# WordPress/WooCommerce - What is the hook for custom category bulk edit?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added bulk action in the WooCommerce product category edit. I just want to know what the hook is when I click on `Apply` to do some actions on selected categories. (Specifically, I want to update all selected categories by updating the `wp_termmeta` table and set the `example` value to `1` or `0`) The only thing that I want is the name of the hook when clicking the `Apply` button in `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product`.

[image: Bulk Action]

Answer (score 1):

Just copy & paste into your functions.php. Enjoy

```
// Note: change all occurrences of "custom_field" with the key of your custom field add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start', 'bbloomer_custom_field_bulk_edit_input' ); function bbloomer_custom_field_bulk_edit_input() { ?> <div class="inline-edit-group"> <label class="alignleft"> <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span> <span class="input-text-wrap"> <input type="text" name="custom_field" class="text" value=""> </span> </label> </div> <?php } add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', 'bbloomer_custom_field_bulk_edit_save' ); function bbloomer_custom_field_bulk_edit_save( $product ) { $post_id = $product->get_id(); if ( isset( $_REQUEST['custom_field'] ) ) { $custom_field = $_REQUEST['custom_field']; update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_field', wc_clean( $custom_field ) ); } }
```

Comment: It didn't work! It didn't even run the function! I put `die('test)` and couldn't see the `test` on the page when clicking on `Apply` button. Not for `woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start` nor `woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save`.